# Magento 2: Product price reindexing error

Tags: magento2

**I initiated php bin/magento indexer:reindex command in my ssh**

But unfortunately one of the indexes gives me an error. Attached below is the error of the product index.

[image]

Comment: Try to run in Database this Query "UPDATE indexer_state SET status = 'valid';"

Comment: Thanks Ankit, I'll try this one and I will let you know if this works.